# summarise_each from dplyr gives error on characters

Tags: r, dplyr

I am seeing an error when using
`dplyr::summarise_each` to summarise character
vectors in a data.frame.

For a simple example, consider this sample data.frame

```
tmp <- data.frame(A=c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d"),
          B=c("u", "v", "v",  NA,  NA, "x", "y"),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tmp

| A | B   |
|---+-----|
| a | u   |
| b | v   |
| b | v   |
| c | nil |
| c | nil |
| d | x   |
```

Now, I want to group this data.frame by "A" and run this little
function on the remaining column:

```
uniqueorna <- function(x) {
  if (length(unique(x)) == 1) {
    unique(x)[1]
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
```

Using `dplyr::summarise_each` works fine on the
first rows:

```
library("dplyr")
tmp[1:6,] %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_each(funs(uniqueorna(.)))

| A | B   |
|---+-----|
| a | u   |
| b | v   |
| c | nil |
| d | x   |
```

But it fails on the full data.frame

```
tmp[1:7,] %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_each(funs(uniqueorna(.)))

Error: expecting a string
```

I'd like to understand why that would fail.  And a way to collapse
different string values into NA like this.

Comment: In your function `uniqueorna` try returning `NA_character_` rather than just `NA`.

Comment: Thanks. That works!  Although I am not too happy to return different NAs conditional on the class of the column...

Comment: Yes, I spent a few minutes trying to see if there is an existing github issue regarding this, but I can't find anything exactly matching this issue. It might be worth filing a bug report with your example, and see what they say.

Comment: I was waiting to see whether the guys would chime in anyway.  Since they did not, the issue is opened now: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1542

Comment: @joran There has been a comment on the issue I created for dplyr.  The suggestion to use `x[NA]` is convenient and seems to work fine.  If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Well, I didn't come up with the answer, so there's no reason why you shouldn't write the answer yourself. You did the work of filing the github issue after all! :)